# Unable to deploy spark history server on Kubernetes POD

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy the spark history server on the kubernetes POD. For that, I am using the following set of commands:-

```
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
helm install stable/spark-history-server --generate-name
```

But while doing so, I am facing the issues and below are the error logs:-

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                      From                               Message
  ----     ------       ----                     ----                               -------
  Warning  FailedMount  7m51s (x129 over 3h31m)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-20240184-1  (combined from similar events): MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "nfs-pv" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/2bc91c0b-a9e8-4af6-9a6a-8e4781079afb/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-pv --scope -- mount -t nfs spark-history-server-1599813147-nfs.default.svc.cluster.local:/ /var/lib/kubelet/pods/2bc91c0b-a9e8-4af6-9a6a-8e4781079afb/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-pv
Output: Running scope as unit run-re958022a7250453abcd26d58efcbf360.scope.
mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server spark-history-server-1599813147-nfs.default.svc.cluster.local: Name or service not known
  Warning  FailedMount  2m51s (x17 over 3h31m)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-20240184-1  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[spark-history-server-1599813147-token-bglz7 data]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is one of the [known issues](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#known-issues):

> Kubernetes installs do not configure the nodes' `resolv.conf` files to
> use the cluster DNS by default, because that process is inherently
> distribution-specific. This should probably be implemented eventually.

There are some workarounds however that you can choose from:

- The NFS is mounted successfully when specified by `ClusterIP` instead of domain name. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3417#issuecomment-670005434).
- Update `resolv.conv` manually on each node.
- Manually write name of service in `/etc/hosts` on all nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the help! With manually adding the service IP of the nfs server in /etc/hosts of all nodes, I was able to resolve the issue